# Extracting a parent class from a group of classes using Reshaprer

Tags: c#, inheritance, resharper

I have a large set of auto generated classes which share about 90% of their properties. Is there a way using Visual Studio or Resharper to extract all the common properties into a parent class and make all the classes descend from the parent?

Comment: Wow can't believe I've got SO stumped - this is a first

Comment: Why do you want to refactor auto generated code as when you re-generate it it will just overwrite all your changes?

Comment: Its just a one off thing, I have generated a batch of classes from a load of XML using xsd.exe, they won't be done again

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's something I'm missing, you can do this with the **Extract Superclass** refactoring (maybe a bit misleading name, in .NET world this would be better called "base class")

On the class name, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, select **Extract Superclass**, select all the properties you want to move. ReSharper will generate a new class, and will move those properties to it.

If you already have such base class, you can select the option **Pull members up**, which will let you "pull" properties to a base class.

Comment: I am aware of the extract superclass command, but I thought that only worked on one class at a time? I have a batch of around 50 classes, all with only minor differences. I want to be able to run a command like extract superclass, but on all classes at the same time.